# Granularity of shapes in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to achieve this in html:

[image]

I do it like this (in red to make it more obvious):

```
span.triangle-bottomleft { 
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 50px solid red;
    border-right: 500px solid transparent;
}
span.triangle-bottomright {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 50px solid red;
    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
}
```

The result is this:
[image]

The pixel is not very granular.  Is it possible to make the sloped line smoother?

Thanks!

Comment: What about considering the use of CSS gradients?

Comment: Have a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bQYU7/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my little experiment, it seems that anti-aliasing works better with the border width hack than the background image solution. There is no easy CSS-only solution to what you're looking for, unfortunately.

Give the following markup:

```
<div class="chevron"></div>
```

You can use the following strategies (view all of this in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/dL2wswfm/1/)

---

## The background image hack

This is achieved by specifying multiple background images, which is supported in CSS3 and modern browsers.

```
.chevron {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(to bottom left, #ccc 0%, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%),
        linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ccc 0%, #ccc 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
    background-position:
        bottom left,
        bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 100%;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

---

## The border hack

While the border hack provides the best visual result, it is not possible to use percentage values for the left and right border widths — you will either have to use absolute values (px, em...) or relative values with respect to the viewport (vh, vw, vmin, vmax). This limits the application to divs that stretches to a known percentage of the viewport:

```
.chevron {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
.chevron::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    border-top: 50px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 50vw solid transparent;
}
.chevron::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    border-top: 50px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 50vw solid transparent;
}
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/dL2wswfm/1/

Comment: Hi Terry - Thanks again for this - One follow up question, this works well in Chrome, but not firefox.  Is there something special I need to do for firefox?

Comment: Which are you referring to — the border or the background solution?

Comment: Both.  If I pull up your jsfiddle on firefox, the line doesn't look smooth.

Comment: Same for Safari.  In fact, just noticed that the border solution doesn't work in safari.

Comment: If that's the case, instead of going for a clean colour stop at 50%, use 49 and 51% respectively: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/dL2wswfm/3/